# How to specify /storage/emulated/legacy using external-path for file provider?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-fileprovider

So in the project I'm working with, pictures are stored to `/sdcard/<app made folder>`, we're sharing the pictures stored here to other apps by using file provider. So when file provider tries to get a uri for the file, it calls getCanonicalPath() which returns the path `/storage/emulated/legacy/<our folder>/<our file>`.

Debugging through file provider, I see that when it checks the file paths its checking through `/storage/emulated/0`

I've tried doing:

```
<external-path path = "storage/emulated/legacy/JCG Camera" name="share_cam_images2" />
```

in filepaths.xml, however when file provider checks for that its resolving it as: `<storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/legacy/JCG Camera/<file>`

How do I specify the path `/storage/emulated/legacy` for file provider?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the exact solution to my problem about specifying the path for file provider in external paths, however I did work around it by saving the files to the path from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of specifying /sdcard/.